# How to create a triple-boot with Win 10, Ubuntu 18.04 & Tails (or any other highly recommended distro)?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, distro-recommendation

Have a 2017 quad core processor, 8gb ddr4 ram but 1tb hdd. How to create a triple-boot with Win 10, Ubuntu 18.04 & Tails (or any other highly recommended distro)?

Comment: Got it thanks  :), went with Robolinux as the 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about tails, but otherwise it's fairly simple. I run Windows 7, Arch Linux and Ubuntu on a PC.

Just make sure you select either BIOS or UEFI installation for all three and don't mix.

You should prepare your hard drive by partitioning it first. Personally I'd use Linux for that. Your preference will do.

Then start by installing Windows. Next the "other" distro. Use Ubuntu last. Grub usually recognizes all operating systems and puts them in the boot manager.

I had no troubles whatsoever. So, according to my experience, that should be the easiest way to get there.

Comment: Got it thanks :), went with Robolinux as the 3rd